# React custom change event handler in form hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wrote a custom React hook for handling forms that exposes a form fields state and change handler factory. It works well for text inputs, but I need to refractor the code to support inputs that expose change events other than the `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`; see the CapitalInput's handler as an example. I would like to avoid exposing the underlying `setFields` function if possible.

A possible solution could be to make the exposed `handleChange` accept a second parameter that gets the value, but I am unsure how to implement that and if it's the best solution.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function useFormFields<FormState>(initialValues: FormState) {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState<FormState>(initialValues);

  function handleChange(key: keyof FormState) {
    // e: any could work here but I would like to avoid that if possible
    return (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
      setFields((fields) => ({ ...fields, [key]: e.target.value }));
  }

  return { fields, handleChange };
}

function CapitalInput({
  value,
  onChange
}: {
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}) {
  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    onChange(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
  }

  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
}

type RegistrationForm = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  capitalInput: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const { fields, handleChange } = useFormFields<RegistrationForm>({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    capitalInput: ""
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <p>First Name</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={fields.firstName}
        onChange={handleChange("firstName")}
      />
      <p>Last Name</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={fields.lastName}
        onChange={handleChange("lastName")}
      />
      <p>This input should make everything capital</p>
      <CapitalInput
        value={fields.capitalInput}
        onChange={handleChange("capitalInput")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use generics

```js
 function handleChange<T extends HTMLElement>(key: keyof FormState) {
    // e: any could work here but I would like to avoid that if possible
    return (e: React.ChangeEvent<T>) =>
      setFields((fields) => ({ ...fields, [key]: e.target.value }));
  }
```

Comment: How does this address the CapitalInput handler case? There is no target property on e. It's just a string per `handleChange` of CapitalInput.

Comment: ternary expression
`setFields((fields) => ({ ...fields, [key]: typeof e === "string" ? e : e.target.value }));` the sky is the limit